# How to include tags in NuGet package using CLI only

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package

I want to add `Tags` for a nuget package.
I do NOT want to use a separate `.nuspec` file (maintenance), 
I'm only using the csproj for packing.

I've tried setting it using `nuget pack -Properties Tags=demo` but that doesn't seem to work..?

I'm trying to solve a bigger problem to create some traceability
using the commit id from the build in the tags? (on VSTS using *Build.SourceVersion*)

References:

- [NuGet CLI ref.](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/nuget/tools/cli-ref-pack)
- [Adding nuget pack as a msbuild target](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Adding-nuget-pack-as-a-msbuild-target)
- [VSTS Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch)

Comment: Editing the *csproj* is ok but should hold placeholders like `$tags$`

Comment: It appears that some metadata can only be set using a nuspec file???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a placeholder in the .nuspec file.

```
<tags>$tags$</tags>
```

and then set the property using the CLI.

```
C:> Nuget pack project.nuspec -Properties tags="MyTags"
```

Answer (score 10):

Actually, contrary to what was said in the other reply, there's a way to do this without a nuspec file.

Refer here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target

NuGet has support for most nuspec elements through csproj as well.

So in your csproj, you would have something like:

`<PackageTags>MyTag1;MyTag2</PackageTags>`

Comment: I think I tried that and it didn't work? Is this for when you create packages using msbuild? .net core csproj?

Comment: @grmbl It works for PackageReference based projects, when you run msbuild /t:pack or dotnet.exe pack.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify `.nuspec` file when adding a tag by `nuget pack` cli.

You can set metadata in `.nuspec` file. You can only modify it manually in `.nuspec` file to modify tags. Besides, you can also modify metadata in `assemblies.cs` file of your project, but it can’t modify tags.

Also you can find details about [`nuget pack -properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-pack#options) option:

> Specifies a list of properties that override values in the project
> file; see Common [MSBuild Project Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties) for property names. The
> Properties argument here is a list of token=value pairs, separated by
> semicolons, where each occurrence of `$token$` in the `.nuspec` file will
> be replaced with the given value. Values can be strings in quotation
> marks. Note that for the "Configuration" property, the default is
> "Debug". To change to a Release configuration, use `-Properties`
> `Configuration=Release`.

So tags are not included in Properties argument, you can only modify `$token$` in `.nuspec` file with `-Properties` arguments.